# AceJump activation

Tags: intellij-idea

Default activation via pressing "ctrl + ;" does not work. Instead of activation I see the following:

After pressing "ctrl + ;" in IntelliJ Idea

[image: 1]

When I change the combination to another one, everything works properly.
Please, help, what does "e" symbol mean within this context and how to handle with it?

Comment: More information is needed for the investigation. Please file a new issue here https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and attach the IDE logs. (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data)

Comment: Does the issue go away if you add -Dawt.ime.disabled=true to the Help | Edit custom VM options and restart the IDE?

Answer (score 0):

It's neither an `Intellij` nor `AceJump` issue. It's a shortcut for entering emojis...

You can turn it off in terminal. Run this:

```
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey "[]"
```

Take a look at this issue:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/692237/ctrl-displays-e-character-and-captures-the-keyboard-shortcut